# AngularJS : $httpBackend regex pattern to pass through requests for certain URL pattern

Tags: regex, angularjs, angular-mock

I am using `ngMockE2E`for mocking some of my services. I want to pass through all the requests which has `/app` in the requests.
how can I specify this condition in regex? For example `app/assets/server/a.json` this URL should not be mocked and it has to pass through. I tried the following code but didn't work.

`$httpBackend.whenGET('/app/').pass through();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/app/).passThrough();
```